# Windows XP Home Install: Unexpected Error (769) occurred at line 5199

Tags: windows-xp

I'm trying to complete a Windows XP install, but am encountering this error:

```
Unexpected Error (769) occurred at line 5199 in D:\xpsprtm\base\boot\setup\setup.c.
Press Any Key To Continue
```

The setup is as follows:

- Intel DX58SO2 Motherboard
- Xenon E5607 CPU
- Single CD/DVD Drive
- 160GB conventional hard drive
- Genuine Windows XP Home OEM with Service Pack 2 (2005), tested elsewhere.

Googling produces few relevant results.  Pressing the "any key" (or, any key) results in nothing, the machine is hung.  The error happens after Windows setup loads all device drivers and "Starts Windows".  Memtest86 runs fine on the machine, ram is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue!  Unnoticed in the media reader on the machine was a 32GB SSD card containing a Linux filesystem.  Removing that solved the problem.  I was tipped off to this possibility by a note elsewhere that D:\xpsprtm was related to hard drive access.

Comment: You know you can accept your answer as the correct answer. Just clicked the check mark under the vote count. You just have to wait a short time delay to accept your own answer. Which you have definitely have exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your Master Boot Record is protected in your BIOS. If not, what BIOS do you have?

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-system/unexpected-error-769-occurred/c73da007-03e7-49fa-96c4-d2f73a0403bd

Also, others have reported that it fails with faulty RAM (I would also suspect that a motherboard could cause this too). Go test your memory with memtest from the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).

http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic94497.html